# Global hotkey to change iTunes ratings

Tags: itunes, keyboard, music

Is there a global hotkey or keyboard shortcut to change ratings in iTunes for the current song?

Some other applications (e.g. Amarok on Linux) have this and I'm missing this functionality from iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

[This post](http://www.lensenergy.com/archives/2010/02/keyboard-control-for-itunes-ra.html) explains a way of doing exactly what you want. It's and old post, though, but it should still work.

Comment: Thanks - this almost worked. It works if I'm in iTunes and the song is selected in the playlist. Pressing `Command+5` will then change the rating of the selected song. It doesn't work if no song is selected (but a song is playing) or if iTunes is in Mini Player mode. I would like to be able to change the rating of the currently playing song.

Comment: I guess a little improvement could be done to the scripts, using the actual playing song instead of the selected one. I'll try to find some time to test it.

Comment: This only seems to work if you are in iTunes and the specific song is selected -- it's not a global shortcut.

Comment: That method still works, but the page is dead. Here's a link to the Archived page: http://web.archive.org/web/20120905231521/http://www.lensenergy.com/archives/2010/02/keyboard-control-for-itunes-ra.html